# HMR's publicHost option not taken into account

Tags: .net, angular, webpack-hmr

### For the background

I was writting a .NET Core 2.2/Angular 7 app for a while, with HMR set and working.
I wanted to profile that app using the Angular DevTools plugin and, to do so, needed to update to Angular 9.

The problem is, that broke my HMR config. HMR was activated and effectively reloading the page when a change was made (the diff even looked correct in DevTools), but was not reflected to the app.

I read that Angular 9 droped HMR support with ivy and was activated again on V11. So I updated to Angular 11 and still no HMR, it's now even totally broken, no more reloading, the sockjs-node calls are facing 404 errors.

Again, I read that HMR support was greatly improved on V12, so, again, I updated to V12 but without imrovement regarding HMR.

### Implementation details

The angular app is served by .NET Core using `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "hmr");` (in developement). The app is split into 2 parts, one in ASP.NET MVC and the other is the actual Angular app, on a special virtual subfolder `/app`, captured using:

```
app.Map("/app", angular =>
{
    angular.UseHttpsRedirection();
    angular.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    angular.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "hmr");
        }
    });
});
```

My HMR script is `"hmr": "ng serve --configuration hmr"` and the HMR configuration as follows:

```
"hmr": {
  "hmr": true,
  "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:hmr",
  "publicHost": "https://localhost.com:44369/app",
  "servePath": "/"
}
```

So, when sockjs tries to reach `https://localhost.com:44369/sockjs-node/info?t=xxxxx`

1. He is obviously not captured by .NET Core's Angular proxy and goes to the MVC app hence the 404 error;
2. HMR seems to ignore the `publicHost` options which wasn't the case with V7.

I've also tried the launch script `"hmr": "ng serve --hmr"` with the same result (how can hmr know the `publicHost` option in that case anyway?).

How can I set my publicHost option properly agiain?

### Edit

As a workaround, I've tried to add an MVC action that catches the `/sockjs-node/...` requests and redirect them to `/app/sockjs-node/...`, but unfortunately that does not work for the websocket one...

### Edit 2

Well well well... my mistake...

As sockjs is a pollyfill to websocket, even if websocket doesn't work, it will be emulated by another plain http method. So, even if the websocket connection fails, this method (while not perfect) works. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, unlike previously, Angular sends all websocket requests to the root.

The only workaround I've found for this issue until now is to use an MVC action to redirect all the `/sockjs-node/...` requests to their correct `/app/sockjs-node/...` form. This will not redirect the websocket call but sockjs will pollyfill it to http requests.

So, I've added this action in one of my controllers:

```
/// <summary>Redirects sockjs-node requests to the app subdirectory to fix HMR issues</summary>
[HttpGet("/sockjs-node/{**path}")]
[HttpPost("/sockjs-node/{**path}")]
public IActionResult AngularHmr(string path)
{
    return RedirectPermanentPreserveMethod("/app/sockjs-node/" + path);
}
```

This solution is far from ideal, but this is only for developpement so it's not so much of a big deal...